# Seeing mDNS domains outside my LAN

Tags: networking, router, dns, mdns

A couple weeks ago, I installed a [new router](https://www.amazon.ca/TP-Link-Wireless-Gigabit-Archer-C7/dp/B00BUSDVBQ). Doing so, I switched [my modem](http://www.hitron-americas.com/product/cda3/cda3/) from router to gateway mode. After doing this, one day my Apple TV started showing up as 'Apple TV (2)'. It's been a busy number of weeks, so I didn't investigate much.

This morning, on my MacBook, I noticed a bunch of computers in my sharing side bar. Investigating, it appears I'm able to see a bunch of machines outside my network.

So, my external IP is in the 99.241.* series. My local IPs are all 192.168.* . When I lookup these machines, they all resolve to 29.* series IPs.

So, after all that background: Where do I put the fault? Is this issue that my modem in router mode was filtering mDNS requests? Or there something misconfigured on my local cable loop?

It's awkward: I appear to be able to browse a shared drive on my neighbour's mac.

Comment: "Or there something misconfigured on my local cable loop?" This is likely. Speak to your ISP.

Comment: Oh I was really hoping it wouldn't be that. Not looking forward to multiple hours on the horn with the support desk :)